# Using Node.js on StackBlitz?

Tags: node.js, firebase, stackblitz

I am trying to handle http requests on my web app which I created using StackBlitz' online IDE (I'm new to a lot of the tools I am going to mention). I am trying to handle a request, then respond with data from my firebase storage.

I learned that to handle http requests I should use Node.js, and I know I can download it to my computer. But I am using StackBlitz, so I am not sure how to get Node.js there.

I tried searching online and someone else sorta asked this question before, without answer though: [Using Node fs on Stackblitz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411209/using-node-fs-on-stackblitz)

Edit: I also heard that 'Express' might work for this, and it has an npm registry that I can use to add it to StackBlitz, trying that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `repl.it` and create your node application there, then you can access the url in your stackblitz angular app.

[repl.it/languages/nodejs](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs)

example (node + express)

https://repl.it/repls/HonoredFussyPdf

Comment: Oh, I've never heard of repl.it before. But it looks like I may just be able to move everything there. There's no reason to split between stackblitz and repl.it right?

Comment: no, stackblitz is for frontend and it's so powerful, repl.it doesn't support angular, so you need to have stackblitz for frontend and repl.it for backend

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you, I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Repl.it has been working great! Thank you so much for the suggestion. I have run into one problem, though. My server is running and I need to end it so that I can restart it. (If I just try starting it again I get an 'address is already in use' error).
Do you know how I can force the server to end?

Comment: @Mike you are welcome, see this https://stackabuse.com/how-to-exit-in-node-js/ in the end it mentioned how to stop the process on repl.it

Comment: Thank you for the article. I have tried every method in there now, by entering them in the console in Repl.it. But when I do Ctrl  + C twice, nothing happens. And if I type .exit, it says '.' is an unexpected token. Any thoughts? Im thinking I might need to start a new project.

Comment: @Mike I don't use repl.it that much, so I would suggest to submit a feedback or bug to them and ask your question

Answer (score 0):

StackBlitz now allows the creation of node apps which can run in the browser (as long as your browser is chrome)